# Неправильная работа конструкции switch-case с методами из разных классов

Tags: java, массивы, сортировка, switch, case

Изучая алгоритмы сортировки массивов, решил накидать простую программу, состоящую из нескольких классов. Пока что в ней 4 класса - один для выбора метода сортировки массива. Остальные три содержат в себе сами функции с алгоритмами сортировки: Bubble Sort, Insertion Sort и Selection Sort. Все алгоритмы работают верно, если их запускать по отдельности в классе ChooseYourSort или прямо в своих классах. Выбор алгоритма осуществляется при помощи конструкции switch-case. Задача методов - отсортировать массив, показать это пошагово, вывести время работы алгоритма. Однако же при выборе блока, в котором выполняются все методы сразу, вывод получается неверным, его я приведу ниже. Пузырьковая отображается верно, сортировки выбором и вставками выдают не то, что должны.

```
public class ChooseYourSort {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {

            System.out.print("Введите длину массива - ");

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            int length = scanner.nextInt();
            int[] arr = new int[length];
            int[] sortedArray;

            System.out.println("Введите числа в массиве: ");

            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                arr[i] = scanner.nextInt();
            }

            System.out.print("Ваш массив: ");
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));

            System.out.println("Выберите метод сортировки массива:\n 0 - All methods\n 1 - Bubble sort\n " +
                    "2 - Selection Sort\n 3 - Insertion Sort");

            int sortingMethod = scanner.nextInt();

            switch (sortingMethod) {
                case 0:
                    System.out.println("Bubble Sort: ");
                    sortedArray = BubbleSort.bubbleSort(arr);
                    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sortedArray));
                    System.out.println();

                    System.out.println("Selection Sort: ");
                    sortedArray = SelectionSort.selectionSort(arr);
                    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sortedArray));
                    System.out.println();

                    System.out.println("Insertion Sort: ");
                    sortedArray = InsertionSort.insertionSort(arr);
                    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sortedArray));
                    System.out.println();
                    break;

                case 1:
                    sortedArray = BubbleSort.bubbleSort(arr);
                    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sortedArray));
                    break;

                case 2:
                    sortedArray = SelectionSort.selectionSort(arr);
                    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sortedArray));
                    break;

                case 3:
                    sortedArray = InsertionSort.insertionSort(arr);
                    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sortedArray));
                    break;
            }

        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("Неверные введенные данные!");
        }

    }
}
```

Неверный вывод:

```
Введите длину массива - 5
Введите числа в массиве: 
5
4
3
2
1
Ваш массив: [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
Выберите метод сортировки массива:
 0 - All methods
 1 - Bubble sort
 2 - Selection Sort
 3 - Insert Sort
0 
Bubble Sort: 
Пошаговая сортировка массива: 
[4, 3, 2, 1, 5]
[3, 2, 1, 4, 5]
[2, 1, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
Время: 179200
Отсортированный массив: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

Selection Sort: 
Пошаговая сортировка массива: 
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
Время: 104100
Отсортированный массив: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

Insert Sort: 
Пошаговая сортировка массива: 
Время: 37200
Отсортированный массив: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

В чём заключается проблема? Опять же, сами методы верны. Их я также приведу ниже для полноты картины. Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Пузырьковая:

```
 static int[] bubbleSort(int[] unsortedArray) {

        int[] sortedArray;
        long start = System.nanoTime();

        System.out.println("Пошаговая сортировка массива: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < unsortedArray.length - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < unsortedArray.length - i - 1; j++)
                if (unsortedArray[j] > unsortedArray[j + 1]) {
                    int temp = unsortedArray[j];
                    unsortedArray[j] = unsortedArray[j + 1];
                    unsortedArray[j + 1] = temp;
                }

            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(unsortedArray));
        }
        sortedArray = unsortedArray;

        long stop = System.nanoTime();
        long time = stop - start;
        System.out.println("Время: " + time);
        System.out.print("Отсортированный массив: ");


        return sortedArray;
    }
```

Вставками:

```
 static int[] insertionSort(int[] unsortedArray) {

        int[] sortedArray;
        int element, insertIndex;
        long start = System.nanoTime();

        System.out.println("Пошаговая сортировка массива: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < unsortedArray.length; i++) {

            element = unsortedArray[i];
            insertIndex = i;

            while (insertIndex > 0 && unsortedArray[insertIndex-1] > element) {

                unsortedArray[insertIndex] = unsortedArray[insertIndex-1];
                insertIndex--;
                unsortedArray[insertIndex] = element;
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(unsortedArray));
            }

        }
        sortedArray = unsortedArray;

        long stop = System.nanoTime();
        long time = stop - start;
        System.out.println("Время: " + time);
        System.out.print("Отсортированный массив: ");

        return sortedArray;
    }
```

Выбором:

```
static int[]  selectionSort(int[] arrayToSort) {

        long start = System.nanoTime();
        int indexMin;
        int[] sortedArray;
        System.out.println("Пошаговая сортировка массива: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayToSort.length-1; i++) {
            indexMin = i;

            for (int j = i; j < arrayToSort.length; j++)
                if (arrayToSort[indexMin] > arrayToSort[j]) indexMin = j;

            int temp = arrayToSort[i];
            arrayToSort[i]  = arrayToSort[indexMin];
            arrayToSort[indexMin] = temp;

            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrayToSort));
        }
        sortedArray = arrayToSort;

        long stop = System.nanoTime();
        long time = stop - start;
        System.out.println("Время: " + time);
        System.out.print("Отсортированный массив: ");

        return sortedArray;
    }
```

Comment: а если ошибочную сортировку вызывать первой что-то изменится?

Comment: Да, всегда работает верно лишь первый метод. Второй просто отображает одинаковый массив, а не пошаговую сортировку. Третий не отображает пошаговую вообще. Я пытался заводить отдельные переменные для каждого метода, но результат был тот же.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы всегда передаете 1 и тот же массив. В вашем случае, вам нужно создать дубль вашего массива, если вы хотите его сортировать для `case = 0`.

То есть, у вас всегда используется

```
                sortedArray = BubbleSort.bubbleSort(arr);
                ....
                sortedArray = SelectionSort.selectionSort(arr);
                ....
                sortedArray = InsertionSort.insertionSort(arr);
```

Вам надо перед каждым из ваших сортировок создавать новый неотсортированны массив, например, так

```
               case 0:
                    int[] notSortedArray1=new int[arr.length];
                    int[] notSortedArray2=new int[arr.length];
                    int[] notSortedArray3=new int[arr.length];
                       for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                           notSortedArray1[i]=arr[i];
                           notSortedArray2[i]=arr[i];
                           notSortedArray3[i]=arr[i];
                               }

                System.out.println("Bubble Sort: ");
                sortedArray= BubbleSort.bubbleSort(notSortedArray1);
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sortedArray));
                System.out.println();

                System.out.println("Selection Sort: ");
                sortedArray= SelectionSort.selectionSort(notSortedArray2);
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sortedArray));
                System.out.println();

                System.out.println("Insertion Sort: ");
                sortedArray= InsertionSort.insertionSort(notSortedArray3);
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sortedArray));
                System.out.println();
                break;
```